# Update NGINX using debian

Tags: debian, upgrade, nginx

I installed Nginx 1.10.3 on Debian 9 and I would like to update him to the latest stable version (1.18.0).

I looked up several websites that explained how to do this, however they all used Ubuntu. It seems to me that the procedure is different than with Debian.

First of all, is it possible to update this version of nginx with my version of debian ? If it is possible, is there an easy way or do I have to uninstall everything and reinstall him ?

I thank you in advance

Yohann C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Official Debian package (backports)

The best you'll get on the official repository is nginx 1.14.1 (at the time of writing this) under stretch-backports. This is a debian maintained distributed and signed nginx package.

https://packages.debian.org/stretch-backports/nginx

This can be done by:

1. adding `deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main` to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file;
2. running `apt-get update`;
3. installing nginx from this repository with `apt-get install -t stretch-backports nginx`.

### Unofficial but more recent version

Follow the instructions on the nginx website (http://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html#Debian) to install the package built by the developers. It's similar to the above with a couple extra steps to import Nginx's keys to validate package signatures. Latest version available today is 1.19.0.

Be mindful that this will add a repository to your system that will permit installation of packages distributed by nginx people. It is an additional source of software that installs and runs on your system.

Comment: Thank you ! I I'll watch this (sorry for the response time).